# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

```
public class AbilityOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public float healthGain = 2f;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        playerHealth.currentHealth += healthGain * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Im getting this error and do not know how to fix it. Anyone know the problem?Assets\Scripts\Medic\AbilityOne.cs(12,9): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerHealth.currentHealth` is an `int`. Try this. It converts the `float` value to an `int` explicitly. The `(int)` part is a called a "cast", so this is what the error message is telling you that is missing.

```
public class AbilityOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    public float healthGain = 2f;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        playerHealth.currentHealth += (int)(healthGain * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

BUT this fixes the error, but I bet it's not the behavior you want. It looks like you'll be adding small fractions of health each frame. That will fail if you try to store those fractions in an `int`. I recommend making `playerHealth.currentHealth` a float. Then the code you have in your question will work fine.

Comment: Thanks so much!